# How to view categories in Powershell v5?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

im running powershell v5 on my machine and i can't seem to run the command

`GET-HELP -Category Provider`.

Is there an alternative to this command which can be used in v5 or is it a command that's available to v3 Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Provider` is a valid category for help topics, **none of the topics that ship with PowerShell use category `Provider` (anymore), as of Windows PowerShell 5.1 / PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x**

- See [GitHub issue #8030](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8030)

The next best thing is to **use a *wildcard-based* search, using the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)'s (positionally implied) `-Name` parameter**:

```bash
Get-Help *provider*
```

This will list all topics with the word `provider` in the name, which comprises both *cmdlets* with the word in the name and *conceptual help topics* (topics whose name starts with `about_`).

If you want **to limit the output to matching *conceptual* help topics** (as `Get-Help -Category Provider` may have done in Windows PowerShell versions *prior to v5.1*):

```bash
Get-Help *provider* -Category HelpFile
# Alternative:
Get-Help about_*provider*
```

---

<sup>[1] The **valid categories** are: `Alias`, `All`, `Class`, `Cmdlet`, `Configuration`, `DefaultHelp`, `DscResource`, `ExternalScript`, `FAQ`, `Filter`, `Function`, `General`, `Glossary`, `HelpFile`, `Provider`, `ScriptCommand`, which correspond to the values of a *non-public* enumeration type, `System.Management.Automation.HelpCategory`; you can obtain these values programmatically with 
`(TabExpansion2 'Get-Help -Category ' -cursorColumn 19).CompletionMatches.CompletionText`.

The **topics that ship with Windows PowerShell v5.1 / as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x span the following categories**: `Alias`, `Cmdlet`, `ExternalScript`, `Filter`, `Function`, `HelpFile`, as obtained with 
`(Get-Help *).Category | % ToString | Sort-Object -Unique`</sup>

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know about that way of using `TabExpansion2` to get the CompletionText. As for PowerShell 5 i had to add `-cursorColumn 19` so it looks like this `(TabExpansion2 'Get-Help -Category ' -cursorColumn 19).CompletionMatches.CompletionText` and now does the tab completion at the end of the supplied string

Comment: Thanks, @An-dir. Good to know that `-cursorColumn 19` is needed in Windows PowerShell; I had only tried in PowerShell (Core) 7.2.6.; I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Powershell 5.1. when I look at `help Get-Help -full`, I read the following:

> Parameters
>
> -Category <System.String[]>
>
> Displays help only for items in the specified category and their aliases. Conceptual articles are in the HelpFile category.
>
> ```
>    Required?                    false
>    Position?                    named
>    Default value                None
>    Accept pipeline input?       False
>    Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

If I do a `Get-Help * | Group-Object Category | Select-Object Name`, I only see the following categories:

- Alias
- Function
- ExternalScript
- Cmdlet
- HelpFile

I get the same categories in PowerShell v7.2